# How to print labels using a Zebra Bluetooth printer from an Angular web application running in the Chrome browser on a mobile phone

Tags: angular, mobile, printing, bluetooth

I am developing a web application in Angular which allows to print labels using a Bluetooth Zebra printer from a mobile phone.
The application is run in the Chrome browser on the mobile phone. However, I am having difficulty establishing a Bluetooth connection to the printer and sending the data to the printer for printing. I have tried searching for solutions, but I haven't found a suitable solution so far.

How can I resolve this issue and print labels from my Angular web app to the Bluetooth Zebra printer?

and this my code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import ZebraBrowserPrintWrapper  from 'zebra-browser-print-wrapper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  
  private browserPrint: any;
  constructor() {
    this.browserPrint = new ZebraBrowserPrintWrapper();
  }
   onPrint() {
    try {
      // Get available printers
      const printers =  this.browserPrint.getAvailablePrinters();
      
      // Let user select printer
      const selectedPrinter = this.selectPrinter(printers);

      // Set the selected printer
      this.browserPrint.setPrinter(selectedPrinter);

      // Check printer status
      const printerStatus =  this.browserPrint.checkPrinterStatus();

      // Check if the printer is ready
      if (printerStatus.isReadyToPrint) {

        // ZPL script to print a simple barcode
        const serial = "0123456789";
        const zpl = `^XA
                    ^BY2,2,100
                    ^FO20,20^BC^FD${serial}^FS
                    ^XZ`;

        // Print the label
        this.browserPrint.print(zpl);

      } else {
        console.log("Error/s", printerStatus.errors);
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
 // Show printer selection dialog and return the selected printer
 private selectPrinter(printers: any[]): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const selectedPrinter = window.prompt("Sélectionnez une imprimante:", printers[0].name);

    if (selectedPrinter) {
      resolve(selectedPrinter);
    } else {
      reject("Aucune imprimante sélectionnée.");
    }
  });
}

}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried this https://www.npmjs.com/package/zebra-browser-print-wrapper but it doesn't work.

Comment: What exactly did not work? Did you get any error messages?

Comment: when I click on the print button I get the following  error                            
 Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')                                                  GET http://localhost:9100/available net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: @Fridiric, you need to install Browser Print from Zebra website (available fro windows, macos, ios and android). That app creates a server at localhost:9100. That will listen to your webapp.